# React-Redux CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions, redux

I want to keep everything, including UI state like section expand/collapse state in Redux store.
I have a section with a table in it, when user clicks the caption, the toggleGroup action is dispatched and `collapsed` flag for group is toggled, which causes a re-render, which actually replaces the DOM node instead of toggling class, which should change the transitioned CSS property, and my transition doesn't work.

```
<div className={classNames({'DealGroup_collapsed': this.props.collapsed})}>
  <div onClick={DISPATCH TOGGLE GROUP ACTION}>
    {this.props.caption}
  </div>
  <div className="DealGroup__wrap">
    <SimpleTable className="DealGroup__table" {...{columns, rows}}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do CSS transitions, when storing UI state in Redux store?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already have a look at `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`?
I don't know if it's what your looking for, but wrapping your components in such a group CSS classes for transition handling get applied.
Simple example:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
        transitionName="your-transition-name"
        transitionEnterTimeout={500} 
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
          {items}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

In your CSS define the transition as follows:

```
.your-transition-name-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.your-transition-name-enter.your-transition-name-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
.your-transition-name-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.your-transition-name-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

React keeps items in DOM until the transition is finished.

See also:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-css-transition-group

Comment: I've read about ReactCSSTransitionGroup, but I don't have items that are added/removed, I have items that are added and on caption click I collapse a section inside the item, but item stays in the DOM.

Comment: Hm, can you provide a running example of what you are trying to achieve?